# How to pin programs to the left part of the Start menu?

Tags: start-menu, windows-10

I want to pin programs to the left part of the Start menu, under the username, the same way as it worked in Windows 7. The area is completely empty (normally it would house the most used programs, but I have disabled that functionality). Using the "Pin to Start menu" context menu option results in a new tile being created in the right part of the start menu (the Metro ghetto). Dragging from within the Start menu or from Explorer to the left area of the Start menu only results in a no symbol icon appearing. The articles I've read (no doubt written at some point during the preview) indicate that dragging should work, but empirical evidence disagrees.

Comment: I, too, would like to know this. I'd really like to see apps I want there, not recently used rubbish.

Comment: @Arjan check the dates, my question predates that one by 19 hours.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately this one did not have an upvoted answer, so the only way to close is the other way around. That said: don't worry about a closure; we're about creating a good Q&A archive, that's all. And if all is well, you'll get your answer.

Comment: @Arjan the original cannot by definition be a duplicate. Please show me a meta decision or a SE directive that says original questions can be closed as dupes of duplicate questions.

Comment: Why are you worried so much? There is no shame in getting your question closed if you're not to blame. And you didn't even upvote the answer you got here, and the other question has more views than this one. So I'd say the other question might even be more useful to you, in due time. Stack Exchange sites are not your personal help forums; we're building Q&As that are useful for future visitors too, where we want each question to be asked only once.

Comment: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/6924/should-older-questions-be-flagged-as-duplicates-of-more-recent-ones-if-those-hav http://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=duplicate+older

Comment: @Arjan because the other question has an accepted answer that I do not find satisfactory, and so it is less likely to attract a good answer. I also believe the practice of closing original questions in favor of dupes discourages people from writing good original questions and doing proper research before asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the windows start menu, you could try using [Classic Start Menu](http://www.classicshell.net/#win7_style-tab) or [Start10](https://www.stardock.com/products/start10/).

## Classic Start Menu

### Pros

- Free
- Highly customizable

### Cons

- Slow on first startup

## Start10

### Pros

- Easy to use
- Seamless integration
- Easy access to metro apps

### Cons

- Paid ($4.99)
- Not very customizable